# StencilJS: Disable auto generation of readme files for some components

Tags: stenciljs, readme

StencilJS auto generation is great: https://stenciljs.com/docs/docs-readme
Is there any way I can disable it for certain components?

Hopefully something simple like adding a line to the top of the tsx file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>If this feature existed I suspect that it would probably be based on a JSDoc comment, likely `@ignore`.</del>

<del>I just tested this by adding those comments and they seem to be ignored since the readme builds anyway.</del>

<del>I suggest opening an feature request issue in [the ionic-team/stencil repository](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil). An important detail would be if those components should also be hidden from the `Dependencies` section of other (non-ignored) components.</del>

<del>You could also try implementing it yourself, I think filtering the components [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/master/src/compiler/docs/readme/index.ts#L15) should work.</del>

---

**Update**

There is an undocumented feature to achieve this by adding `@internal` to the JSDoc.

I just successfully tested it for components as well as only for specific properties in Stencil 1.12.5 but from looking at the git history it seems this has been available for a while (a couple of years at least).

**Examples:**

**Ignore component:**

```
/** @internal **/
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {...}
```

**Single property**

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() visibleProp = '';

  /** @internal **/
  @Prop() hiddenProp = '';
}
```